# Fancybox watermark probleme image size

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I append a div into the fancybox to display a watermark in fancybox gallery

```
<script>
$(".fancybox2").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        /* Add watermark to gallery elements only */
        if (this.group.length > 1) {
            $('<div class="watermarker"></div>')
                .bind("", function (e) {
                return false; /* Disables right click */
            }).prependTo($.fancybox.inner);
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

How can i only append the div into the fancybox if the image size is bigger than X?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add the criteria to the `if` statement like :

```
if (this.group.length > 1 && this.width > x && this.height > y)
```

The full code (slightly different than yours)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox2").fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            /* Add watermark to gallery elements only */
            if (this.group.length > 1 && this.width > 800) {
                $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                    return false;
                });
                $('<div />', {
                    "class": "watermarker",
                    style: "width:" + this.width + "px; height:" + this.height + "px;"
                }).prependTo($.fancybox.inner);
            }
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

Notice the `contextmenu` is *bound* to the fancybox `wrap` and not to the `watermark` since right-click can be achieved *hovering* the gallery navigation arrows. If you want to restrict the right-click in all the images including those outside of the gallery, then just take the `.bind()` method out of the `if` statement.

Also notice I am dynamically setting the `width` and the `height` of the `watermark` the same size as the fancybox *inner* box, but I could set the rest of its properties with a CSS rule.

Last, notice the applied *class* is declared in quotes since *class* is a reserved javascript keyword.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0bh1zL6c/)**
In the demo, only the second image (which is wider than "x") will have a watermark